# How many four digit numbers greater than $5000$ can be formed by using the digits $4$, $5$, $6$ and $7$ with no repetitions?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many four digit numbers greater than $5000$ can be formed by using the digits $4$, $5$, $6$ and $7$?( Repetition of the digits is not allowed)

According to me answer should be 24

Thousand place can be filled in 4 ways
Hundred place can be filled in 3 ways
Tens place can be filled in 2 ways 
Units place can be filled in 1 way

But the actual answer is 18

Solution says
Thousand's place can be filled in 3 ways. 
Hundred's also in 3 ways
Tens also in 2 ways
Units place can be filled in 1 way

How?

Comment: If you fill in the thousands place with a 4, then something goes wrong, right?

Comment: Oh,yes! Understood @JyrkiLahtonen